# How to get all the values of 2nd loop output into the 3rd loop end_idx variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, nested-loops

This question may have been already answered but after much time searching SO and the net I did not find a suitable answer.

I have 3 consecutive loops as follows:

```
    w = my_text0.get(1.0, END).split()

    data = []
    # get & set the matching dict keys and values
    for i in w:
        if i in [*dictionary]:
            word = i.title()
            my_text.insert(END, word)
            my_text.insert(END, ", " + dictionary[i] + "\n")

            keys_len = len(word)
            print("keys_len", keys_len)
            data.append(keys_len)

    print("data", data)

    # print("keys_len", keys_len)
    # get text widget lines count
    txtwidg_lnescnt = int(my_text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0])

    for j in range(0, len(data)):
        k_l = data[j]
        print("k_l", k_l)
    print("k_l out", k_l)

    # get index start and end for tag_add method
    for k in range(1, txtwidg_lnescnt):
        lne_idx = k
        str_idx = f"{lne_idx}.0"
        end_idx = f"{lne_idx}.{k_l}"
        print("end_idx", end_idx)
        my_text.tag_add("start", str_idx, end_idx)
        my_text.tag_config(
            "start",
            background="red",
            foreground="black",
            font=bdfont,
        )
```

I need the `k_l` values from the `2nd loop` to be processed in the `3rd loop`.
But currently only the last value `(9)` from the `2nd loop` is processed.

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
keys_len 5
keys_len 6
keys_len 9
data [5, 6, 9]
k_l 5
k_l 6
k_l 9
k_l out 9
end_idx 1.9
end_idx 2.9
end_idx 3.9
```

**I need it as this:**

```
keys_len 5
keys_len 6
keys_len 9
data [5, 6, 9]
k_l 5
k_l 6
k_l 9
k_l out 9
end_idx 1.5
end_idx 2.6
end_idx 3.9
```

I'm familiar with the `append to an empty list method` to store all the values from a loop.

But I can't repeat it here as it was already done in the `1st loop`.

I also tried using the `return from a separate function method` but it outputs as in a nested loop and that's not what I need:

```
def mykeyslengths():
    # get the user's entered words
    w = my_text0.get(1.0, END).split()

    data = []
    # get & set the matching dict keys and values
    for i in w:
        word = i

        keys_len = len(word)
        print("keys_lenzz", keys_len)
        data.append(keys_len)

    for j in range(0, len(data)):
        k_l = data[j]
        print("k_l", k_l)

    return k_l


def generate():
    # Clear The text
    my_text.delete(1.0, END)

    # get the user's entered words
    w = my_text0.get(1.0, END).split()

    # data = []
    # get & set the matching dict keys and values
    for i in w:
        if i in [*dictionary]:
            word = i.title()
            my_text.insert(END, word)
            my_text.insert(END, ", " + dictionary[i] + "\n")

    #         keys_len = len(word)
    #         print("keys_len", keys_len)
    #         data.append(keys_len)

    # print("data", data)

    # print("keys_len", keys_len)
    # get text widget lines count
    txtwidg_lnescnt = int(my_text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0])

    # for j in range(0, len(data)):
    #     k_l = data[j]
    #     print("k_l", k_l)
    # print("k_l out", k_l)

    # get index start and end for tag_add method
    for k in range(1, txtwidg_lnescnt):
        lne_idx = k
        str_idx = f"{lne_idx}.0"
        end_idx = f"{lne_idx}.{mykeyslengths()}"
        print("end_idx", end_idx)
        my_text.tag_add("start", str_idx, end_idx)
        my_text.tag_config(
            "start",
            background="red",
            foreground="black",
            font=bdfont,
        )
```

Which output as this:

```
keys_lenzz 5
keys_lenzz 6
keys_lenzz 9
k_l 5
k_l 6
k_l 9
end_idx 1.9
keys_lenzz 5
keys_lenzz 6
keys_lenzz 9
k_l 5
k_l 6
k_l 9
end_idx 2.9
keys_lenzz 5
keys_lenzz 6
keys_lenzz 9
k_l 5
k_l 6
k_l 9
end_idx 3.9
```

If that was not clear from the examples, I need the lengths `5, 6, 9` to `bold` and modify the `backgrounds` and `foregrounds` of the respective substrings lengths determined by the `end_idx` variable's values with a `tkinter` `tag_add` end index property.

The problem I get currently is that all 3 substrings (the dictionary keys) are the same lengths (9) whereas they should all be distinct as per their respective lengths (5, 6, 9).

Comment: The values are still in data, no?  Can't you just use data[lne_idx-1]?  BTW you could clean up your code by not using so many indexes.  For example in your 2nd loop just do `for k_l in data: print('k_l', k_l)`

Comment: That works great thanks. But I'd never have guessed that was a solution. I still don't understand it fully. `data[1-1] (at idx 0) = 5` , `data [2-1] (at idx 1) = 6` etc. It works. I think I did not expect `txtwidg_lnescnt` to equal `data`, and that's why it works. Is it? loops are not my b&b. Sorry for the code but I need a step by step approach as I always have a hard time with non standard looping use or combining loops. Thanks again Be well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    w = my_text0.get(1.0, END).split()

data = []
# get & set the matching dict keys and values
for i in w:
    if i in [*dictionary]:
        word = i.title()
        my_text.insert(END, word)
        my_text.insert(END, ", " + dictionary[i] + "\n")

        keys_len = len(word)
        print("keys_len", keys_len)
        data.append(keys_len)

print("data", data)

# print("keys_len", keys_len)
# get text widget lines count
txtwidg_lnescnt = int(my_text.index("end-1c").split(".")[0])

for j in range(0, len(data)):
    k_l = data[j]
    print("k_l", k_l)
print("k_l out", k_l)

# get index start and end for tag_add method
for k in range(1, txtwidg_lnescnt):
    lne_idx = k
    str_idx = f"{lne_idx}.0"
    end_idx = f"{lne_idx}.{data[k-1]}"
    print("end_idx", end_idx)
    my_text.tag_add("start", str_idx, end_idx)
    my_text.tag_config(
        "start",
        background="red",
        foreground="black",
        font=bdfont,
    )
```

Comment: Yes it works thanks. I'll need to review it to cement the idea. Be Well!